# how to provide background image of RAPHAEL bar graph

Tags: raphael, background-image, bar-chart, graphael, customizing

I am creating a graph by RAPHAEL... 
Now I need to customized look and feel of the rendered graph, by providing image on backgroun of graph.

Colors can be passed as array to set the background color of graph but, is their any way to provide background of graphs?(it should be work on IE7 and 8 also)

I've tried to manupulate the graph by taking "path" element by script and changing the "fill" attribute of that path.

Problem is that:
In IE the paths are created by RVML tag(not path) thats why the procedure stated is not working fro IE.

Can any one help me to provide any solution "to customize background(background image) of bar graph created by RAPHAEL".

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

This is just an advice, an idea.

Since you are using `JavaScript`, try `ExtJs 4`. This framework provides professional charts and there are more lightweight in my opinion than `Raphael`s graphs. **http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example**

ExtJs gives you a lot more flexibility for tweaking and changing the graph's interafce. You can easily add backgroung here.

[image]

Another really good alternative is Google. I am not sure about background color here, but it is very easy to use.

 **https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery**

[image]